# Volatile vs Atomic

Tags: java, concurrency, volatile

В чем разница между модификатором `volatile` и классами из `java.util.concurrent.atomic`? Что такого умеют последние, чего невозможно добиться посредством `volatile`? Почему?

И приведите, пожалуйста, use case для `volatile`? В каких ситуациях он (модификатор) все же востребован и достаточен?

Answer (score 10):

`volatile` обеспечивает только видимость изменений, а классы `Atomic*` дают еще и атомарность изменений.

Простой пример - вам нужно проинкрементить счетчик и вернуть значение. Если поле счетчика будет обычным `volatile int` - возможна ситуация, когда два разных потока сначала проведут инкремент, а потом оба заберут результат двух инкрементов.

Если же взять `AtomicInteger`, будет гарантирована атомарность, и каждый поток получит правильный результат.

---

Типичное применение `volatile`:

- флаги (например, флаг выполнения потока);
- поля в POJO, которые используются только для хранения данных, когда по какой-то причине нет возможности использовать final-поля.

Comment: Помимо вышеописанного, volatile обеспечивают атомарность записи в примитивы типов long и double

Comment: @AndreyM.Stepanov верно, на 32хразрядных машинах. Но это не очень актуально,  т.к. на 64хразрядных long и double атомарны.

Comment: Вы не поясните в связи с вашим ответом: почему volatile могут служить заменой именой final полям - ведь ничто не мешает обновить volatile поле, в то время как final играет иную роль? И если на то пошло, не могли бы привести пример, какие именно причины могут заставить отказаться от final  в этом контексте в пользу volatile?
Спасибо

Comment: Я не имел в виду, что volatile - замена final. Final, разумеется, более сильное ограничение. Но оба они дают гарантию видимости значений из другого потока.

Answer (score 0):

volatile не позволяет потокам кэшировать переменную.